# Template matching with different template sizes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I've already seen questions like this before, but those ones refer to image scaling, which means aspect ratio is same all the time. My goal is to analyze each image ([Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYQpC.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezf6S.png)) and determine [the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAIU2.png) location (X and Y coordinates) and size (width and height of the recognized one as precise as possible) and write them into variables using single not warped [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAIU2.png).
I'm not really into programming, that's just something I need for my project. I know the basics, so there's no need to explain a lot, if there's not big of a deal. I would really appreciate any help. [Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTdL1.png)

UPD:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
img1 = cv2.imread('template.png')
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.imread('image.png')
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

orb = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=500)
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
match_img = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches[:50], None)
cv2.imshow('', match_img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: that's a little more complicated than "simple" template matching. you need invariance to translation (ok), but not just one dimension of scale but **two** (individual axes). you might be able to apply feature description, feature matching, then OpenCV's `findHomography` (or lesser transformation). or try something based on AI/DNNs

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz I've researched for some information, but it seems quite complicated. Could you please solve this out for me if you can? I'll be really grateful.
So, I have a lot of unneccesary points and I don't know how to get rid of them and how to get the X and Y coordinates of the beginning and the end of the found template pattern. Maybe the method I'm using is not the right one?

https://imgur.com/oIV3oQJ

I've also updated the question, so you can see the code I've used.

Comment: @nathancy Thank you for sharing. I've already checked that one out, but it isn't the case for mine and for an unknown reason. It works with images from the original one, but never for the ones I use. It could be because the warping is really strong, but it is how it is in 撃 and 手 (and it also differs from one symbol to another, it could be warped the other way like in 劧 or 㨌 or 搿, etc), so I'll be really happy if you would be able to solve this.
https://imgur.com/nOgjEiT

Comment: I'm afraid simple image processing will not be enough since in the eyes of a computer, template matching is essentially doing pixel-to-pixel comparison. In your case, your template and target have scale as well as transformation shifts. You will need to switch to deep/machine learning and train your own model for this. Simple image processing will not be able to solve it unfortunately